# CR vs. LF in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I use AppleScript to process text that I take from Keynote presenter notes. Usually I go through the text paragraph by paragraph, but recently I found an instance where a »soft return« (ASCII 13 aka CR) was used instead of a real return (ASCII 10 aka LF).

I now try to pre-process the text in order to get rid of the CR in favour of LFs, but the following approach fails for no apparent reason:

```
on purgeCR(aText)
     set my text item delimiters to {ASCII character 13}
     return text items of aText as text
end purgeCR
```

When I feed this with text that has CRs and LFs, they will all stay the same, and I don'rt really know why. for some reason, CR does not work as a text item delimiter.

Another attempt was to use the shell:

```
set z to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of a & " | tr '\r' '\n' " without altering line endings
```

Also no luck.

For some reason, CR messes with AppleScript's ability to process text, or I'm just not seeing something very obvious, because stupid.

I have a working script that goes through the text character by character, but there has to be an easier (and faster) way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, run in **Script Editor**,  will replace the *carriage returns* with *line feeds*:

```
set foo to "This text contains\rinstead of\n which is what is expected.\rHow do I get rid of them?"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set bar to text items of foo
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set foo to text items of bar as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

return foo
```

---

**Update to address comment:**

As a simple test under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6 using **Keynote** version 10.2 (7028.0.88), I created a new presentation with one slide and this was the only *window* open in **Keynote**, while not modifying it from its defaults.

In **Script Editor**, I ran the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set foo to "foo\rbar"

ASCII number of character 4 of foo

tell application "Keynote" to tell slide 1 of front document
    set presenter notes to foo
    set bar to presenter notes
end tell

ASCII number of character 4 of bar

tell application "Keynote" to tell slide 1 of front document
    set foo to presenter notes
end tell

ASCII number of character 4 of foo

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set bar to text items of foo
log bar
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set foo to text items of bar as text
log foo
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

ASCII number of character 4 of foo

tell application "Keynote" to tell slide 1 of front document
    set presenter notes to foo
    set bar to presenter notes
end tell

ASCII number of character 4 of bar
```

In the **Replies** pane of **Script Editor** it showed the following:

```
tell current application
    ASCII number "
"
        --> 13
end tell
tell application "Keynote"
    set presenter notes of slide 1 of document 1 to "foo
bar"
    get presenter notes of slide 1 of document 1
        --> "foo
bar"
end tell
tell current application
    ASCII number "
"
        --> 13
end tell
tell application "Keynote"
    get presenter notes of slide 1 of document 1
        --> "foo
bar"
end tell
tell current application
    ASCII number "
"
        --> 13
    (*foo, bar*)
    (*foo
bar*)
    ASCII number "
"
        --> 10
end tell
tell application "Keynote"
    set presenter notes of slide 1 of document 1 to "foo
bar"
    get presenter notes of slide 1 of document 1
        --> "foo
bar"
end tell
tell current application
    ASCII number "
"
        --> 10
end tell
Result:
10
```

As you can see, the *carriage return* was indeed replaced with a *line feed*.

If you do not get the same results, the only suggestion I can make is before you set the *presenter notes* to the *text* that has had the *carriage returns* replaced with *line feeds*, first set the *presenter notes* to `""`, then set to the corrected *text*.

Comment: now that is interesting. let me show this example, where i use your approach side by side  to mangle the text of a keynote presenters note text, and the text you used in your example.  
  
not sure how to show a picture, but here: http://igw.tuwien.ac.at/designlehren/side_by_side.png. 
  
now no matter what is in the text i get from keynote, how can that CR survive the treatment that obviously works well on a constructed text?

Comment: @peterpur, What's interesting is, if I copy and paste from a text file that has _carriage returns_ in the text into Presenter Notes of a slide, they are automatically converted to _line feeds_, so my question to you is... How did you get _carriage returns_ into Presenter Notes to begin with?  -- BTW I'm using  **Keynote** version 10.2 (7028.0.88) on **macOS Catalina** 10.15.6.

Comment: @peterpur, Please see my updated answer. I was able to introduce a _carriage return_ into the `presenter notes` and then retrieve it and replace it with a _line feed_. So, my original answer still stands as it does work.

Comment: shift-return creates a CR in the presenter notes.  i will look at your edited answer, thank you for your efforts!