# osascript 'do shell script' line endings

Tags: shell, osascript

I'm trying to debug an larger osascript 'do shell script' program and have narrowed the problem down to a much shorter repro case that I don't understand at all. Here's the repro case:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "echo 123; echo 45; echo 6"'
```

Gives me the output:

```
653
```

Can anybody explain what's going on? It's almost like 'do shell script' does not properly handle line endings, or tries to print everything on one line.

Comment: This very much looks like you have carriage returns in place of line feeds.

Comment: Same output from `osascript -e $'do shell script "printf \'%s\\n\' 123 45 6"'`, which is identical from what you'd see from `printf '%s\r' 123 45 6; echo`

Comment: This is very closely related to [CR vs LF in applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386031/cr-vs-lf-in-applescript), though the `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed` therein isn't sufficient to resolve it.

Comment: Take a look at: `osascript -e $'set output to do shell script "printf \'%s\\n\' 123 45 6"\nset AppleScript\'s text item delimiters to return\nreturn text items of output'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applescript replaces \n characters with \r characters when reading the output of a shell script. You can tell this is happening by running the output through `od -c`:

```
$ osascript -e 'do shell script "echo 123; echo 45; echo 6"' | od -c
0000000    1   2   3  \r   4   5  \r   6  \n                            
0000011
```

To turn this off, use the `without altering line endings` parameter.

```sh
 osascript -e 'do shell script "echo 123; echo 45; echo 6" without altering line endings'
```

See [Technical Note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG2-HOW_DOES_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_GET_THE_RESULT___HOW_DO_I_RETURN_A_SHELL_VARIABLE_TO_MY_APPLESCRIPT_) for more.